# iOS/objective-c: NSJSONSerialization graceful failure

Tags: ios, objective-c

When there is no data (as can happen even when there is an Internet connection due to server issues), the following crashes.  Is there a way using the error term to make it degrade gracefully or do I have to use another if statement such as is there data in the feed before calling JSONSerialization.  Would like to find an alternative to another if statement.  In actually, the if statement below is earlier in the code and all the ifs get very complicated.

```
if (internet) {
//some code
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonFeed
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
//some code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to change your `if` condition to `if (jsonFeed)`, regardless of why it's nil?

Answer (score 2):

The only other option would be to have a method/function that wraps the call to `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` and returns nil if `jsonFeed` is nil.  You'd just be hiding the if statement, but if you need this in many places, it may be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization will handle *any* valid NSData object with *any* contents whatsoever. Passing a nil NSData is a programming error which rightfully throws an exception.

You may for example pass

```
jsonfeed ?: [NSData data]
```

instead of jsonfeed. But then why are you testing "if (internet)"? That's nonsense. What counts is not whether you have an internet connection or not, what counts is whether you had a connection to the server that returned a result.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the test for Internet is earlier in the code to determine if the user is online or offline.  If you are suggesting checking the validity of the result from the server every time that is exactly what I am asking.  Which you have not answered.